# Fill a ZedGraph curve with different color segments?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

Is it possible to fill a line graph (like in the filled curve demo) with different color segments?

Answer (score 0):

i think u can't do that.
but we can use multiple curve to achieve that.

maybe something like :

```
    LineItem myCurv1 = myPanx.AddCurve("", list1, color1, SymbolType.None);
    LineItem myCurv2 = myPanx.AddCurve("", list2, color2, SymbolType.None);
    LineItem myCurv3 = myPanx.AddCurve("", list3, color3, SymbolType.None);
```

where the x of each curve is simultan like :

```
    list1 => (0,1),(1,5),(2,19),(3,9)
    list1 => (3,1),(4,5),(5,19),(6,9)
    list1 => (6,1),(7,5),(8,19),(9,9)
```